# SQL if condition then remove row from query

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I have a problem with one specific month in my dataset. For people who have Status=new in October, I want to check they also have the same status in November. If not, I don't want that row in the query output (but I don't want to delete it from the table).

I made a sample table in db fiddle:

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
  id INT ,
  month DATE,
  status VARCHAR
);
INSERT INTO customer VALUES (1, TO_DATE('31/1/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'processing');
INSERT INTO customer VALUES (1, TO_DATE('31/10/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'new');
INSERT INTO customer VALUES (1, TO_DATE('30/11/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'new');
INSERT INTO customer VALUES (2, TO_DATE('31/1/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'processing');
INSERT INTO customer VALUES (2, TO_DATE('30/11/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'processing');
INSERT INTO customer VALUES (2, TO_DATE('31/12/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'new');
INSERT INTO customer VALUES (3, TO_DATE('31/1/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'processing');
INSERT INTO customer VALUES (3, TO_DATE('31/10/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'new');
INSERT INTO customer VALUES (3, TO_DATE('30/11/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'processing');
select * from customer
```

And my desired output is in this image: [image]

i.e. the first month where status = 'new' - unless the first month is October, and status went back to 'processing' in November. So it would start with something like this,

```
select min(month),id from customer
where status='new'
group by id
```

I'm a bit stumped on how to go about the rest. I imagine it'll be something along the lines of case when([month='20221031'& Status='new')&[month='20221130' & Status!='new') then 'do something to exclude that row', but I can't find the actual valid syntax.
Thanks for any suggestions! :)

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please provide some sample data and the expected result together with you attempt

Comment: Is there a preferred format to provide this in?

Comment: DDL and DML are, by far, the best way for sample data. Otherwise use markdown tables (markdown tables are always fine for expected results). *Do **not*** use images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kinda convoluted requirements you got there.

```sql
CREATE TABLE customer (
  id INT ,
  month DATE,
  status VARCHAR(30)
);
INSERT INTO customer VALUES (1, ('2022-01-31'), 'processing');
INSERT INTO customer VALUES (1, ('2022-10-31'), 'new');
INSERT INTO customer VALUES (1, ('2022-11-30'), 'new');
INSERT INTO customer VALUES (2, ('2022-01-31'), 'processing');
INSERT INTO customer VALUES (2, ('2022-11-30'), 'processing');
INSERT INTO customer VALUES (2, ('2022-12-31'), 'new');
INSERT INTO customer VALUES (3, ('2022-01-31'), 'processing');
INSERT INTO customer VALUES (3, ('2022-10-31'), 'new');
INSERT INTO customer VALUES (3, ('2022-11-30'), 'processing');

select *
  from (
   select *, row_number() over(partition by id order by month) AS sort
    from (
    select *, lead(status) over(partition by id order by month) as nextStatus
    from customer c
  ) c
  where c.status = 'new'
  ) x
where sort = 1
and not (datepart(month, month) = 10 and ISNULL(nextStatus, '') = 'processing')
```

This works by following: first get next status partition by id, this have to be done before filtering on status, otherwise you won't get correct data. Then you filter out new status and rank them by month.

Finally you take the first row, but not if first row is of month 10 and next status is processing. Since there might be NULL in nextStatus, we're careful and do an ISNULL.